# Has Ubuntu gone case-insensitive?

Tags: dropbox

So, I have a folder on my computer which contains these two files (and other files)

```
disc membership.pdf
disc membership.pdf (Case Conflict 1)
```

And I have a folder on an external drive which contains the file

```
DISC membership.pdf
```

I copy the file from the external drive to the computer harddrive, and find that it is renamed

```
disc membership.pdf (Case Conflict 2)
```

Why?

The folder on the computer is contained within a Dropbox folder. Could that be a reason?

Comment: or your extern drive has a windows file system

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Dropbox is doing this, not Ubuntu, because it would cause problems if you synced with a Windows machine at some point as Windows is case-insensitive.

From [Dropbox help](https://www.dropbox.com/help/145):

> **Case conflicts**
>
> Linux computers allow you to have two files or folders with the same name but different capitalization. However, Mac and Windows won't differentiate file or folder names by case. Therefore, if Dropbox comes across linux directories named "Sample folder" and "sample folder" (lowercase "s"), it will still sync both folders to Mac and Windows computers, but **one will appear as a copy of the original file and appended with case conflict**.